# Adding multiple items to a model in catalyst

Tags: mysql, perl, catalyst

I am building a Perl website using Catalyst.  The site will allow users to upload a large (100,000 lines or more) text file for processing.  I need to convert each line to a row in a MySQL database.

I have been using Catalyst's very nice `DBIC::Schema` model, as detailed in [the tutorial](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aTutorial%3a:04_BasicCRUD):

```
$c->model('DB::Book')->create({
        title   => $title,
        rating  => $rating,
    });
```

This inserts a row into the appropriate database.  However, it is much too slow to insert tens of thousands of rows one at a time.  Is there a way to use this interface to insert multiple rows with one query?

It should be simple to determine from the documentation, but I can't figure out where `create()` is documented.

I have tried the obvious, an array of hash references:

```
my @rows = (
    { foo=>1,bar=>2 },
    { foo=>2,bar=>3 }
);

$c->model('DB::MyTable')->create(@rows);
```

However, it does not work. It only inserts the first row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for create can be found in the [DBIx::Class::ResultSet docs](http://search.cpan.org/~abraxxa/DBIx-Class-0.08209/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#create). create only inserts a single row, for bulk inserts you can use [populate](http://search.cpan.org/~abraxxa/DBIx-Class-0.08209/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#populate) from the same class.

Comment: This solved it.  The insert operation went from 30 minutes to a few seconds.  Your help is much appreciated!